# Preventing dash from going through walls using raycast

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Currently, I want to make a dash for the player in a 2D game in unity. I'm using game objects to the left and right of the player to use raycasts to check the distance from a wall in a certain area. If its too close to a wall, I need it to dash only that distance (to the wall) instead of the full distance (behind/through the wall).

This is my code for dashing in my player movement (DashCheckLeft is -0.5 from the player) (DashCheckRight is 0.5 from the player):

```
    public float dashDistance = 3f;
    float distance;
    public Transform DashCheckLeft;
    public Transform DashCheckRight;

 private void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            Debug.Log("Dashed");
            Dash();

 private void FixedUpdate() {       
        RaycastHit2D hitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(DashCheckLeft.position, Vector2.left, -dashDistance);
        RaycastHit2D hitRight = Physics2D.Raycast(DashCheckRight.position, Vector2.right, dashDistance);
        if(hitLeft.collider != null) {
            distance = Mathf.Abs(hitLeft.point.x - transform.position.x);
        }
        else if(hitRight.collider != null) {
            distance = Mathf.Abs(hitRight.point.x - transform.position.x);
        }
        else {
            distance = dashDistance;
        }
    }
 private void Dash() {
        rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x + distance, rb.position.y);
        }
```

The problem now is that apperently I'm only dashing the distance between the player and the DashChecks (0.5f) instead of the intended 3f and I believe it may be because the raycasts are hitting the collider of the player somehow, but changing my player to the "Ignore Raycast" layer makes it fall into the floor, and also doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this problem, and found the answer. Basically, your raycasts were detecting the player's collider too. There is a simple fix for this. You should just add the fourth argument to your raycast. The fourth argument is a *LayerMask*. A LayerMask is like a tag, but you can have several on at the same time. This is what I changed the code to (I made some extra adjustments too):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float dashDistance = 3f;
    public LayerMask floor;
    float distance;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            RaycastHit2D left = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right, dashDistance, floor);
            RaycastHit2D right = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, dashDistance, floor);
            if (left.collider != null)
            {
                print("left");
                distance = Mathf.Abs(left.point.x - transform.position.x);
                distance = -distance;
            }
            else if (right.collider != null)
            {
                print("right");
                distance = Mathf.Abs(right.point.x - transform.position.x);
            }
            else
            {
                distance = dashDistance;
            }
            print(distance);

            Debug.Log("Dashed");
            Dash();
        }
        void Dash()
        {
            rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x + distance, rb.position.y);
        }
    }
}
```

(when I say 'world objects', I mean the objects that make up the terrain. For example the ground or trees) You should add a new layer by clicking on the world objects. Then, you should look at the top of the inspector, then click the 'Layer `Default`' dropdown menu, and click the 'Add Layer...' button. Then write a new name on that list. Go back to the world game object, and click the same dropdown menu, and select the layer that you want for the world. You should make sure that **all** of the world objects have the **same layer**. Go back to the player object, and in the inspector, set the 'floor' variable to the same layer as the world. If that didn't make sense, here is a [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html#:%7E:text=Layers%201%20Creating%20Layers.%20The%20first%20step%20is,culling%20mask.%20...%204%20Casting%20Rays%20Selectively.%20) of how to set layers.

Comment: Either accept the answer or close the question to signal to other developers that this is solved.